# XML hierarchy tree parsing

Tags: jquery, xml

So I have this XML file as shown above, I want to parse the field `outputId`.

```
-<personRepresentaion>
      <theId>1324</theId>
      <name>John</name>
      <topY>1</topY>
      <leftX>0</leftX>
      <height>10</height>
      <width>12</width>
     -<relationships>
       <inputId>1324</inputId>
       <outputId>1325</outputId>
      </relationships>
    </personRepresentaion>
```

Currently I parse the other fields like the following:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("personRepresentaion"); 
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
var y =x[i].getElementsByTagName("theId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue //this gets me theId

//now I want to get the outputId
var outputId = x[i].getElementsByTagName("outputId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue //what is wrong with this?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do it using jquery like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var _personXML = $('<personRepresentaion><theId>1324</theId><name>John</name><topY>1</topY><leftX>0</leftX><height>10</height><width>12</width><relationships><inputId>1324</inputId><outputId>1325</outputId></relationships></personRepresentaion>');

    alert("the id: "+_personXML.find("theId").eq(0).text());    
    _personXML.find("relationships").each(function(){
        alert("Output id: "+$(this).find("outputId").eq(0).text());
    });

});
```

**UPDATE:** ****Demo****: http://jsfiddle.net/R74XG/